# start align number by one

Tags: align

I have an align list of equations, but it's starting by number 2 cause I have another align list in another frame, so how can I force it to start by number 1?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   439^2 &\equiv 1360\equiv 2^4\cdot 5\cdot 17       \\ % I have here (2)
   441^2 &\equiv 3120\equiv 2^4\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 13\\ % (3)
   444^2 &\equiv 5775\equiv 3\cdot 5^2\cdot 7\cdot 11\\ % (4)
   445^2 &\equiv 6664\equiv 2^3\cdot 7^2\cdot 17     \\ % (5)
   447^2 &\equiv 8448\equiv 2^8\cdot 3\cdot 11       \\ % (6)
   449^2 &\equiv 3120\equiv 2^11\cdot 5                 % (7)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could insert the instruction

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
```

immediately before `\begin{align}`.